# Junit test with mock for rest controller method

Tags: java, junit

I have a actually create simple webservice and i want to add new junit test.
I have a method where I add people to teams.
This is my method(in rest controller):

```
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> addPeopleToTeam(@PathVariable Long teamId, @PathVariable Long personId) {
    TeamsAndPersonsId teamsAndPersonsId = new TeamsAndPersonsId(personId, teamId);
    teamService.findTeamById(teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId());
    personService.findById(teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId());
    teamService.addPersonsToTeams(personId, teamId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(teamsAndPersonsId);

}
```

For this method i want to wrote a Junit test but something is going wrong:/
This is my test class with method:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TeamControllerTest {

    private ObjectMapper mappingObject = new ObjectMapper();
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private TeamService teamService;
    private PersonService personService;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(new TeamController(teamService, personService))
                .setControllerAdvice(GlobalExceptionHandler.class)
                .build();
    }
        @Test
    public void shouldAddPersonToTeam() throws Exception{
        TeamDto teamDto = prepareTeamDto();
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto(1L, "Bob", "Noob", "mail@first.pl", "Warszawa", "APPS", "Developer");
        doNothing().when(teamService).createTeam(teamDto);
        doNothing().when(personService).addPerson(personDto);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}",1,1))

                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

    private TeamDto prepareTeamDto() {
        return new TeamDto(1L, "Jan", "local", "wawa", 6);
    }
```

Actually for this method i have this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception the 2nd time is called
```

Answer (score 0):

`doNothing()` is used only for void methods, like is described in your error message, in your case you have to use something like:

```
when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn(Reponse.ok().build());
```

Note: you have to override `@equals` method in your `TeamDto` class

Comment: Thanks good to know i'm newbie in test. But when I add Your solution I can't use Response :/ This is coyote implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, I guess that `TeamService.createTeam` or `PersonService.addPerson`  does not have `void` return type and you can mock `doNothing` behaviour only on methods, which returns `void`. Also you are missing  `@Mock` annotation on `PersonService` field.

In spring boot tests, it is better to use [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation. And for controller tests it is better to use  [@WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), you can then skip the configuration done in your setup method:)

Comment: also i think that in your use case, you should verify that methods `createTeam` and  `addPerson` are called on given mocks, rather then try to mock some `doNothing` behaviour. See http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1 in case of Mockito

Answer (score 0):

```
@InjectMocks
Controller controllerMock;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerMock).build();
}
```

where - ControllerMock will be Mock of Controller class